# Can the Order of the Mutant blood hunter increase an ability score past 20 using their mutagens?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ability-scores, blood-hunter

I am playing an Artificer 5/Blood Hunter 2. I was thinking of taking another level of Blood Hunter and picking the Order of the Mutant. The Mutagencraft feature lets me concoct and consume a mutagen to gain certain temporary benefits.

I currently have an Int score of 20. If I use the Sagacity mutagen, can it increase my Int score to 23?

Comment: Is there something about the description of the mutagen that is confusing? The answer to your question here seems to be quite plainly written in the description of the Sagacity mutagen.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 11):

#### The Sagacity mutagen increases your Intelligence maximum.

It's written right in the mutagen description:

> **Sagacity**
> Your Intelligence score increases by 3, *as does your Intelligence maximum*. This bonus increases by 1 at 11th and 18th level.